# SQL Server 2014 - UPSERT XML Multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2014, xml

We have an input like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Orders xmlns:jjsales:api:sales>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>334</OrderID>
            <AmountPaid currencyID="EUR">17.10</AmountPaid>
            <UserID>marc58</UserID>
            <ShippingAddress>
                <Name>Marc Juppé</Name>
                <Address>Rue</Address>
                <City>Paris</City>
                <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
                <Country>FR</Country>
                <Phone>333333333</Phone>
                <PostalCode>22222</PostalCode>
             </ShippingAddress>
             <ShippingCosts>4.50</ShippingCosts>
             <Lines>
                <Line>
                   <Details>
                        <ItemID>3664</ItemID>
                        <Store>47</Store>
                        <Title>MCPU DDA010</Title>
                        <SKU>mmx</SKU>
                    </Details>
                    <LineID>1111</LineID>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Price currencyID="EUR">6.2</Price>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                   <Details>
                        <ItemID>3665</ItemID>
                        <Store>45</Store>
                        <Title>MCPU DFZ42</Title>
                        <SKU>mmy</SKU>
                    </Details>
                    <LineID>1112</LineID>
                    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                    <Price currencyID="EUR">3.2</Price>
                </Line>
            </Lines>
        </Order>
    </Orders>
```

and we are currently importing data into Sales Table with a query like this:

```
    INSERT INTO Sales (ItemID,Store,Title,SKU,Quantity,Price,OrderID,AmountPaid,UserID,ShippingCosts)

    SELECT I.X.value('(Details/ItemID/text())[1]', 'int') as ItemID,
           I.X.value('(Details/Store/text())[1]', 'int') as Store,
           I.X.value('(Details/Title/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Title,
           I.X.value('(Details/SKU/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SKU,
           I.X.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'int') as Quantity,
           I.X.value('(Price/text())[1]', 'decimal(11,2)') as Quantity,
           O.X.value('(OrderID/text())[1]', 'int') as OrderID,
           O.X.value('(AmountPaid/text())[1]', 'decimal(11,2)') as AmountPaid,
           O.X.value('(UserID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as UserID,
           O.X.value('(ShippingCosts/text())[1]', 'decimal(11,2)') as ShippingCosts
    FROM @XML.nodes('/Orders/Order') as O(X)
    CROSS APPLY O.X.nodes('Lines/Line') as I(X)
```

but now we need to update records that already exists checking Lines.Line.LineID

Since do not want to use MERGE, we thought it was easy to solve adding the usual

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Sales where LineID=@LineID)
        INSERT INTO Sales () SELECT ....
    ELSE
        UPDATE Sales SET ItemID=..., Store=..., ... WHERE LineID=@LineID
```

but the value of `@LineID` in inside the XML and has to be calculated while parsing the XML

And discovered have no idea how to get it

Can suggest how to get the value of `LineID` while parsing the XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can suggest how to get the value of LineID while parsing the XML?

You can take this output in a variable to check for existence.

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Orders>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>334</OrderID>
            <AmountPaid currencyID="EUR">17.10</AmountPaid>
            <UserID>marc58</UserID>
            <ShippingAddress>
                <Name>Marc Juppé</Name>
                <Address>Rue</Address>
                <City>Paris</City>
                <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
                <Country>FR</Country>
                <Phone>333333333</Phone>
                <PostalCode>22222</PostalCode>
             </ShippingAddress>
             <ShippingCosts>4.50</ShippingCosts>
             <Lines>
                <Line>
                   <Details>
                        <ItemID>3664</ItemID>
                        <Store>47</Store>
                        <Title>MCPU DDA010</Title>
                        <SKU>mmx</SKU>
                    </Details>
                    <LineID>1111</LineID>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Price currencyID="EUR">6.2</Price>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                   <Details>
                        <ItemID>3665</ItemID>
                        <Store>45</Store>
                        <Title>MCPU DFZ42</Title>
                        <SKU>mmy</SKU>
                    </Details>
                    <LineID>1112</LineID>
                    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                    <Price currencyID="EUR">3.2</Price>
                </Line>
            </Lines>
        </Order>
    </Orders>
'


   SELECT
      LineId = XCol.value('(LineID)[1]','int')
      FROM 
      @input.nodes('/Orders/Order/Lines/Line') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

Here is the result set I get:

> LineId
>
> 1111
>
> 1112

Comment: Sorry but I think I've not understood: once  I got these result what shall I do?
put them in a temp table and iterate the current query for the 2 (or more) Lines?

Comment: Well, I (tried to) explain it in the question: we need to upsert the sales table, having `LineID` as key.
Therefore, yes, how to get the value of `LineID`, but inside the procedure of upsert, if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can hold the values in a temp table and pass each one in the variable @LineID.

Comment: hmm.. currently we are parsing the data in the script and passing the "clean" XML to the SP for each Line: if this is the solution better to continue in the old way: I thought there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You might consider replacing the variable with the select statement I showed (or something that sort).